# Translating short AppleScript into Windows VBScript

Tags: vbscript, applescript, windows-scripting

Knowing only name of "unique job number" subfolder, I'm trying to write VBScript which quickly returns name of "client name" folder which contains my "unique job number" subfolder

**This is my folder structure:**

Client 1

-unique job number

-unique job number

-unique job number

Client 2

-unique job number

-unique job number

-unique job number

With some help here I have found applescript to do this (I was thinking to run script in my Mac):

```
set client_folders to "/Volumes/Jobs/2014"
set my_folder to "TD57706"
set clientName to (do shell script "find " & quoted form of client_folders & " -type d -name " & quoted form of my_folder & " -exec dirname {} +")
```

Unfortunately my clients folder structure is on another computer (Windows) in local network and I think this is way my Mac have problem to search it quickly (around 600 clients folders). I need to run this code on this Windows computer instead on my Mac.

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: If you haven't any specific problem (another than you must use Windows) your question is off topic.

Comment: SO is not a free translation service. Please show us what you have tried and what specific problem you encountered.

Comment: Sorry to break rules, I'm still new here. I've edited question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and loop through all SubFolders in a folder. This code should do the trick.

```
'Declare variables to be used  
Dim oFSO  
Dim myFolder  
Dim FolderToSearch
Dim FolderToFind  

'Define variables  
'Access a Scripting.FileSystemObject  
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

'Get the folder to be searched
FolderToSearch = "C:\Folder_To_Be_Searched"
FolderToFind = "TD57706"

'Set the current directory to a folder object  
Set myFolder = oFSO.GetFolder( FolderToSearch )  

'Loop through each of the files in the folder  
For each myFolder in myFolder.SubFolders

    'Output the name of each file
    if myFolder.Name = FolderToFind Then
        wscript.echo myFolder.Path
    End if

Next
```

For more information about the Scripting.FileSystemObject check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx

This is a slightly modified version of an example that I posted to my blog which may be of interest to you as well [VBSCRIPT – Loop through all files in a directory](https://seanwoodward-public.sharepoint.com/Blog/Post/13/VBSCRIPT-%E2%80%93-Loop-through-all-files-in-a-directory).

Thanks,

Sean W.

Comment: This will only check immediate subfolders of the given folder whereas the `find` command will search for a folder with the given name anywhere below the given folder. Also, please don't encourage bad questions by gracing them with an answer.

Comment: Thank a lot Sean. This works, but only when FolderToFind is directly in FolderToSearch. I need name of the folder which is between C:\FolderToSearch\..(name of folder I need)..\FolderToFind